# Fody/Mono.Cecil: Hide Lines in debugger

Tags: c#, .net, pdb-files, mono.cecil, fody

I am developing a fody addin (using mono.cecil) and inject some code at the beginning of a method. I want the debugger to step over the injected code.

I found some information here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/10/10/479016.aspx

So I tried to update the sequence point of the injected instructions to line number 0xfeefee.

I am doing this using the following code:

```
    public static void Inject(MethodDefinition method, List<Instruction> instructions)
    {
        var methodInstructions = method.Body.Instructions;

        int index = 0;
        var sequencePoint = method.Body.Instructions
            .Where(instruction => instruction.SequencePoint != null)
            .Select(instruction => instruction.SequencePoint)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (method.HasBody && sequencePoint != null && sequencePoint.Document != null)
        {
            var instruction = instructions[0];
            instruction.SequencePoint = new SequencePoint(sequencePoint.Document);
            instruction.SequencePoint.StartLine = 0xfeefee;
            instruction.SequencePoint.EndLine = 0xfeefee;
        }

        foreach (var instruction in instructions)
        {
            methodInstructions.Insert(index++, instruction);
        }

        method.Body.OptimizeMacros();
    }
```

This should be basically the same code as the NullGuard.Fody project uses, but it does not work. I am still getting a source not available info from visual studio when trying to debug into a method where the code was injected.

Do I need to do anything else, so that the pdb file is updated?

Answer (score 1):

Try remove the `Where` from the query to select the first sequence point.

You should only need to add your hidden sequence point if the first instruction of the method has a sequence point.